# NullPointerException - Drawable.setBounds - probably due to fragment transitions

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, transformation

I'm getting following error and I don't know why (this error is VERY RARE and not reproducable for me):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.ImageView.animateTransform(ImageView.java:1126)
at android.transition.ChangeImageTransform$2.set(ChangeImageTransform.java:64)
at android.transition.ChangeImageTransform$2.set(ChangeImageTransform.java:61)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:938)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:952)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1207)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1248)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:659)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I think it has to do with the android `Fragment` and `Activity` transitions, but I'm not sure... The above is the complete stacktrace.

Maybe interesting, I'm using the **support-library**

Does anyone have an idea where this comes from and how I can prevent it?

**EDIT**

**As written in the comments:**

- **I don't know from which code block this exception comes from**
- **I don't animate anything myself**
- **I assume, this problem comes from transactions between fragments (the only animations I use in my app)**

**EDIT2**

I did not know that I have to make sure an `ImageView` does have a content. This may lead to the above error, an `ImageView` that does not have an image yet.

Comment: post you code where you get this `Exception`

Comment: I quote myself "The above is the complete stacktrace"... I can't see anything relatet to my code... so above stacktrace is all I know. That's why I don't know where to start...

Comment: @prom85 can you add your code too? it is hard to debug w/o it. Somewhere you pass to 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds' a null.

Comment: As I said, I only get the above exception. And I don't manually animate things, so that's why I suppose, that it's related to fragment transactions... I don't know where the exception comes from, I just can't say what code block is responsible for it...

Comment: Please pass your code, which is causing an exception. Now, we can only guess what is causing it. I think, Drawable on which you are calling `setBounds(...)` method is being destroyed during Activity or Fragment lifecycle and you try to access it when it doesn't exist anymore. Another case could be a situation where Drawable wasn't initialized, but you are trying to access it.

Comment: please read my comments above. I just can't do that... I even edited my question now to state that again

Comment: This may actually be a known bug in Android 5.0 that was fixed in 5.1. As far as I know there was no real workaround than to disable a custom transition for the affected version. And indeed this is very tricky to repro (unless you have many millions users, then it becomes quite common an we could see only 5.0 was affected).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Fragment or Activity transition is trying to animate an  ImageView which has no drawable set. Ensure you always have a Drawable set for your ImageView when you animate it with ChangeImageTransform (or disable this kind of animation)

Comment: good point. I think that could be the reason. Actually I'm using Picasso to load images, I'll check that and test that

Comment: Make sure you set a placeholder image so that when Picasso hasn't finished loading, the transition will not crash.

Comment: I will do that. Currently I'm partly using custom targets and show/hide a ProgressBar. With no placeholder... That probably is the reason for my problem

Comment: this seems to have solved the problem. Didn't get any crashes like that anymore. Thanks

Comment: FYI, this bug was [fixed in 5.1.0](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java/?v=diff&id2=5.0.2_r1#1131).

Answer (score 0):

I followed answer made by @BladeCoder in this thread. His solution was just one part if you used Universal Image Loader.

After adding placeholder to ImageView, you need also to put some image or color (depends of your needs) to XML.